# Does $\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{2}}{\sqrt {\sin x\tan x}}\space dx $ diverge or converge?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I am trying to decide if this integral converges or diverges, I got stuck calculating, so I tried to use the comparison test, but I'm not sure of which function to choose, I would appreciate any hints and help in how to choose which function to compare my integral with, or any tips in general about how to approach these questions. 
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try simplifying the integrand first. This has an elementary antiderivative.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thanks, I was so overwhelmed I didn't even notice and went to try a comparison test, do you have any tips on when to really go for a comparison test?

Comment: @Pwaol You can always attempt a comparison test, it is safer since searching for an anti-derivative requires good intuition. For example, once you write the above as $\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{\cos x}}$, it is clear that putting $y = \cos x$ gives a nice form to the expression. Mostly , comparison is faster than searching for an antiderivative. For example, were we comparing, then since $\sin$ is bounded, it's enough to look at how $\sqrt{\tan x}$ behaves near $1$, and that's like $(\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2} - x})^{-1}$, so it depends if this is integrable near $1$.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Thanks for the explanation, I wonder just how do you find which function behaves like $tanx$, or in general how to find functions that behave nearly the same, is it just from experience? or there's a way to find them?

Comment: @Pwaol It is from the so called Taylor formulas. See,  the Taylor formulas provide good approximations near a point. For example, the Taylor series for $\tan x$ at $x=0$ begins like $\tan x = x + ...$, so we say that $\tan x \approx x$ for $x  \approx 0$. Similarly known approximations are $\sin x \approx x$ for $x \approx 0$ and $\cos x \approx 1 - \frac{x^2}{2}$ for $x \approx 0$. Now, you basically decide integrability at points where the function is blowing up, and once you insert these powers of $x$ in place of the trigonometric functions you know whether integrability holds or not.

Comment: @Pwaol These are usually found in elementary textbooks in calculus, which are studied I think in advanced school mathematics. It depends where you are from, but if you've seen integration you will see this soon too.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Thanks so much, yeah I've learnt about taylor's polynomial, I didn't think of it being this useful here, appreciate the help. got alot of revising to do :)

Comment: @Pwaol Use similar questions on the site to get intuition about how convergence is decided. You can choose to read some of the more advanced answers too, because the subject is quite large, and sometimes the Taylor formula can't be used(floor functions etc.) but at your level, I think what I've said is just about right.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I will! appreciate all the help. I'm sorry for digging on this again but I can't seem to get how we reach $\sqrt { \frac {\pi } {2} -x} $ from taylor's polynomial. I think I got the part where we searched near $1$ (its close to $\frac {\pi } {2}$ and easy to calc?), but then in the second element in taylor's polynomial I would get $tanx$ derivative at $1$ multiplied by $x-1$, which is $\frac {1}{cos^2(1)}*(x-1)$, I couldn't see how you easily reached $\sqrt { \frac {\pi } {2} -x} $.

Comment: @Pwaol We are looking at how $\sqrt{\tan x}$ behaves near $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$ , since this is the part where the function blows up so we can't decipher integrability. Use the formula $\frac 1{\tan x} = \tan(\frac{\pi}{2} - x)$ to get that $\sqrt{\tan x}$ near $x= \frac \pi 2$ behaves like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\tan(\frac{\pi}{2} - x)}}$ , where $\frac{\pi}2 - x$ is near $0$. Now $\tan y \approx y$ for $y$ close to $0$, and then you just get $\frac 1{\sqrt{\frac \pi 2 - x}}$, which is integrable by a comparison test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**\begin{align}\lim_{x\to\pi/2^-}\frac{\sqrt{\sin(x)\tan(x)}}{\frac1{\sqrt{\pi/2-x}}}&=\lim_{x\to\pi/2^-}\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{-\frac{\cos(x)}{x-\pi/2}}}\\&=1.\end{align}